# Gnome2 Keyring displaying Large Green Tick

Tags: password, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-keyring

When an application wants to access a stored key or certificate in Gnome 2 Key Storage I get a password box with a green bordered white box with a green tick inside. The box overlays the password field and looks improper. Could anyone else confirm this is normal behavior?

This occurs when unlocking *Gnome2 Key Storage* in the *Passwords and Keys* application. See attached image.
[image]

I am running Gnome 3 shell on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered this here is the answer. The Green Tick shown is a remember the password opt-in. It seems as though the size has out-grown its container. Simply put, if you click on the Green Tick at the same level as the text to the right of it the image will change based on your preferences. I note that this is not a problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome.